# How to reinstall the iPhone app in ad hoc distribution

Tags: iphone

I am using ad hoc distribution for my iPhone app. It works very well. The only problem is when I update my app or create a new binary and want to install this new version on device, I need to delete the old version. Like although I drag and drop the new version in iTunes application, it does not over write the previous version even after I do sync. It might be becoz the app already exists in the device. So I need to delete it to reinstall it. How do I make sure the app gets updated to the new version and I dont loose the data from the previous app. Data I mean the database. Please note I am just formating the UI and not even touching the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that you must increase the version number in your main plist file for iTunes to install a new version of your app.

Comment: plist file for iTunes. Can you explain a little more about the same. Like what file, where it is located and what parameter we need to change exactly.